# How long (maximum length) can USB 2.0 signal travel using hubs?

Tags: usb-2, data-transfer

I know that the maximum distance USB 2.0 cable can be is 5mtrs.

I'm not sure of the implementation using hubs and the length it can reach.

Are there **alternate methods** of **increasing the signal** to reach longer distances, to defy the 5mtrs limit of data transfer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

USB 2.0 cables are not limited by signal degradation, but rather by a maximum response time of 1500ns before the host will consider the command lost. Using longer cables is possible with extremely low resistance cables, but I don't know how one could obtain such a cable; it would likely have to be custom-manufactured.

USB-over-Cat5 adapters can run cables for longer distances, up to 50m in some cases.

Comment: could you point out any of such adapters availability at any stores?

Comment: don't bother I think I could locate some thanks for the replies

Answer (score 2):

You could use a USB Extender (with cat5 network cable) to extend the distance to 150 feet.

Another option might be to use a wireless USB hub.

Comment: could you please quote the source of this information, there has been much debate about daisy chaining and data transmission drops. Sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: @rzlines - No inconvenience.  I reviewed my documentation and found an error. I confused daisy chain with straight line connection and have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use an unpowered (ie powered by the USB), USB over cat5 extender at work. The only problem I have found is a drop in volts which meant I had to add a powered hub at the other end.

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest and cost-effective would be to run a 5 m cable to where-ever, and only hook up the data pins with a 5 V adapter then run it again. All this in theory and not tested. I guess you can run up to 10, maybe 15 m whithout data loss or delay.

My plan is to buy 5 cheap USB webcams an modify the enclosures to make CCTV cameras with IR lights. Cost-effective and handy. Then run them from a PC with the method I described above. I won't push video signals more than 10 m.

I read up on 6-core alarm cables. It works nicely. I always buy a roll or two. Nice and thin, but not too thin, about the same as USB.

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever want to connect file storage devices to it there are any number of cheap cable routers that will share a FAT/FAT32/NTFS formatted usb drive over Ethernet. Some of them work OK with printers too. Webcams etc - you're probably out of luck :/